# How to test an object is deallocated?

Tags: swift, xctest, retain-cycle, xctestcase, strong-reference-cycle

I have some mock code that performs a retain cycle (or at least in my mind it should). Here it is:

```swift
protocol MyService {
    func perform(completion: @escaping () -> Void)
}

class MyServiceImpl: MyService {
    func perform(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: completion)
    }
}

class MyObject {
    let service: MyService
    var didComplete = false

    init(service: MyService) {
        self.service = service
    }

    func doSomething(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        service.perform {
            self.didComplete = true
            completion()
        }
    }
}
```

Notice in the `MyObject.doSomething()` method we capture `self` strongly in the service completion. This should result in a retain cycle, since `MyObject` is holding a reference to `service` and `service` holds a reference to `MyObject`. (Please enlighten me if I'm wrong.

Next, we write our test to catch this memory leak:

```swift
final class DemoTests: XCTestCase {

    func test_demo() {
        let service = MyServiceImpl()
        let myObject = MyObject(service: service)
        addTeardownBlock { [weak myObject, weak service] in
            XCTAssertNil(myObject)
            XCTAssertNil(service)
        }
        let exp = expectation(description: "wait for complete")
        
        myObject.doSomething {
            exp.fulfill()
        }
        
        wait(for: [exp], timeout: 1)
        XCTAssertTrue(myObject.didComplete)
    }
}
```

This test is **passing**. It shouldn't.

What am I doing wrong, or what is that I don't understand about retain cycles or the `XCTest` framework?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: There is indeed no retain cycle here.

Comment: It's obviously not a problem in this case, but, as a general rule, you should never rely on your objects being deallocated in any particular time scale, if you pass it to code you do not control. If Apple changed their implementation of `DispatchQueue` to hold on to the closure for even a few seconds, your test would start failing, even though there is no incorrect code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no retain cycle here. The closure indeed captures `self` strongly, and `self` also keeps a strong reference to `MyServiceImpl`. However, when the closure is passed to `MyServiceImpl`, `MyServiceImpl` does not keep a strong reference of the closure. It simply passes it to `DispatchQueue`, which will promptly discard the closure after it's done running. The graph looks like of like this:

```
DispatchQueue.main ---> closure ---> MyObject ----> MyServiceImpl
```

To get a retain cycle, `MyService` can keep a reference to the closure:

```
class MyServiceImpl: MyService {
    
    var closure: (() -> Void)?
    func perform(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
        closure = completion // note this line
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.1, execute: completion)
    }
}
```

Now there is a retain cycle and your test fails. You can also see this in the memory graph debugger in Xcode.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

There is no retain cycle. `DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter` will release the closure after execution, then the reference counter reaches 0 and the closure is deallocated and also decrements the reference count to `myObject`